# How to set session in Class Symfony

Tags: symfony

This service is supposed to update the session locale when a user login and/or update his locale:

This service works well when a user login (it set the session locale to the  user locale) but when a user update his locale (and don't log out), the session locale doesn't change.

How can I do that ?

Here is my service:

```
se.locale.interactive_login_listener:
        class: SE\UserBundle\EventSubscriber\UserLocaleListener
        calls:
            - [ setSession, [ "@session" ] ]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate, method: setPersistLocaleForAuthenticatedUser }
```

My class:

```
class UserLocaleListener
{
    private $session;

    public function setSession(Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function setLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if ($lang = $user->getLocale()) {
            $event->getRequest()->setLocale($lang);
            $this->session->set('_locale', $lang);
        }
    }

    public function setPersistLocaleForAuthenticatedUser(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $user = $args->getObject();
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }
        $this->session->set('_locale', $user->getLocale());
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user=$this->getUser();
        dump($user->getLocale());//->en
        $user->setLocale('fr');
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        dump($user->getLocale());//->fr
        dump($request->getLocale());//->en
    }
```

Comment: I would like add that, in my controller if i do this:

`$this->get('session')->set('_locale', 'fr');`

just after the flush, it changes the session locale to fr, don't know if it can help

Comment: Why would you think that setting the session would immediately update the request?